# Can someone help me interpret these findings?

Tags: regression

So here is what I did, I input the command, `davis.mod <- lm(weight ~ repwt, data=Davis)`. It's a bi-variate regression that is using reported weight to estimate actual weight.

When i summarized the data, this is what I get.

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ repwt, data = Davis)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -7.048  -1.868  -0.728   0.601 108.705 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   5.3363     3.0369   1.757   0.0806
repwt         0.9278     0.0453  20.484   <2e-16

Residual standard error: 8.419 on 181 degrees of freedom
  (17 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.6986,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.697 
F-statistic: 419.6 on 1 and 181 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> confint(davis.mod)
                 2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.6560394 11.328560
repwt        0.8384665  1.017219
```

I do not know how to interpret the findings at all... Can someone explain what the intercepts and the confidence intervals mean?

Comment: Note for people wanting to reproduce this analysis: I believe the data set `Davis` being used here is the one in the `car` package.

Comment: You should clarify what you already know. Have you ever done a confidence interval for a mean, for example, and so know what a confidence interval is? Do you know from mathematics what the meanings of the intercept and slope of a line are?

Comment: I do understand those things you mentioned, I'm just looking for a verbal interpretation for the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think this might fall under `self-study`. Could you please read the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag wiki info, and (presumably) add the tag? (e.g. are you trying to give a verbal interpretation for some exercise for a subject?)

Comment: I just started using R recently, so I'm just running through some basic tutorials, trying to make sense of the numbers that R is spitting out.